# Undefined offset: 1 in CompilesLoops.php laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, nested-loops

I have a services list. Now I want to add sub-services to services list. I have two tables 'services' and 'sub-services' with foreign key constraint 'service_id'. Now, I want to show the 'services' and related 'sub-services' in master.blade.php. For services it was working fine, but, when trying with sub-services then getting this error. Would someone please help to get the expected result.
In master.blade.php-

```
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Services</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu services-dropdown" role="menu">
         @forelse(App\Model\Service::all() as $service)
           <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href="{{ url('services/'.$service->slug) }}">{{ $service->title }}</a>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-services">
                   @foreach(App\Model\SubService::where('service_id', '=',$service->id)->get()) as $subservice)
                     <li>
                       <a href="{{ url('sub-services/'.$subservice->slug) }}">{{ $subservice->title }}</a>
                     </li>
                   @endforeach
                  </ul>
           </li>
         @empty

         @endforelse
      </ul>
</li>
```

Two tables are here-
1.Services table
[image: service]

2.Sub-services table
[image: sub-service]

Comment: waht is the error, can you post ir

Comment: Undefined offset: 1 in CompilesLoops.php (line 95)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax. You're using redundant `)` near the `get()`, so change it to:

```
@foreach(App\Model\SubService::where('service_id', $service->id)->get() as $subservice)
```

Also, as I say in my best practices repo, [you shouldn't execute queries in a Blade template](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#do-not-execute-queries-in-blade-templates-and-use-eager-loading-n--1-problem). Consider moving the logic to a controller.

Comment: It's getting all 'sub-services' list at a time. I want to show only in which service has related sub-service.

Comment: @RashedHasan it's not related to the original question and issue. You should accept the answer if it fixed the error you've got and create a new question if you'll not be able to solve the new problem by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This error also occurs when you don't close you loop correctly.

Use `@foreach()` to start a loop and `@endforeach` to close the same loop.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bad way to write a logic part in blade file.I would suggest you to move it to controller because if in case you need to change the code you have to edit blade page.As well as please make use of relationship for fetching the data you can relate your Service with SubService 
E.g
Service.php (model file)

```
 public function subServices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\SubService');
    }
```

SubService.php (model file)

```
public function services()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Service','service_id');
    }
```

your blade code:

```
 @forelse(App\Model\Service::all() as $service)
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a href="{{ url('services/'.$service->slug) }}">{{ $service->title }}</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-services">
                    @foreach($service->subServices as $subservice)
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ url('sub-services/'.$subservice->slug) }}">{{ $subservice->title }}</a>
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </li>
        @empty

    @endforelse
```